# Discord JS reaction.emoji returns undefined

Tags: javascript, undefined, discord, emoji

I need to get a specific reaction from a specific message. The problem is when I read any reaction, they return undefined.

```
client.on('messageReactionAdd', (reaction, user) => {
    console.log(reaction.emoji);
}
```

Comment: Java is not JavaScript. Please retag this question correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this

```
client.on('messageReactionAdd', (reaction, user) => {
    reaction.message.channel.send(`${user} reacted to ${reaction.message.author}  with  ${reaction._emoji.name}`);
});
```

your bot will send the emoji in the corresponding text channel.

When you get an undefined reference, it's always a good idea to console.log the parent object. In this case: `console.log(reaction)`. You can see that it was `_emoji` and not `emoji`.